# How to convert old vb6 project to vb.net in visual studio 2008?

Tags: vb6-migration

I have an old vb6 project and I want to convert vb6 project code to vb.net in Visual Studio 2008. By using upgrade wizard in vs2008 I opened .vbp(Old vb6) file.

It is successfully opened, but I got an error. Please give me the appropriate solution for this.

> upgrade failed when I tried to convert vb6 project to vb.net using upgrade
>       wizard in visual studio 2008. Plz solve this issue.Thanks in advance.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRsDw.jpg]

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not the upgrade error you got from Visual Studio. Please provide some more details. In addition: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you followed the recommendation in the exception dialog? Installed VB6 and compiled the project successfully.

Comment: Yes i followed those recommendations and also vb6 project is compiled and executed successfully in virtual player of windows xp operating system. Still i got the same error

Comment: Just to be clear: That would be on the _same machine_ that you are using to convert the project? It seems the wizard is unable to find a bunch of components.

Comment: No,Sir actually i have to convert this project using visual studiio 2008 on windows 7. But the currently this project on virtual machine. We are taken the project files from virtual player.

Comment: We are trying to upgrade those files to vb.net using vs2008

Comment: What if you install VS2008 on that virtual XP and try to upgrade there?

Comment: Ok sure sir i will instal on virtual player and i will try to upgrade there.

Comment: The upgrade wizard is quite old. The company that built it has a newer version you can buy. Check out https://www.mobilize.net/solution/vb-upgrade-companion

Comment: This problem was not related to a deficiency in the VBUW: it was due to components not being installed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that the libraries referenced by your VB6 project are not installed and registered on your Visual Studio 2008 machine.

Does this project run in VB6 on the same machine?  If not, you will need to copy all of the missing OCX files to your VS2008 machine and use `regsvr32.exe` to register each one individually before attempting your conversion.